# Running qgis_process from Linux terminal

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, linux

I am currently working with coordinate data that I cannot take off of a remote server and I need to run QGIS processes on this data. However, in downloading QGIS 3.18.3 onto the remote machine through conda forge and running `qgis_process` I was met with the following error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

And this is very confusing to me that `xcb` is trying to even connect to a display given that `qgis_process` allows for running processes without one.

I am very new to this.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out yesterday, type this into the terminal *before* you run `qgis_process`.

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

This command enables qgis/qt to run headless (without a display). Using this, you could also do a bash script like this:

```
#filename: some_server_tool.sh
#!/bin/bash

# make Q headless
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen

# run qgis
qgis_process sometool.model3 ...
```